# Why all methods of View.class in Android always throw a exception

Tags: java, android

**I'm doing a class exercise then I found a thing make me confuse:**

- I'm using Android Studio
- After using Ctrl + click on getContext()
- Android Studio direct me into View.class
- In here, I saw every methods always throw an exception as figure below

[image]

**Question:**

- When I call getContext(), it return a instance of Context. Why in method's body it just throw an exception?
- I thought .class is an execute file for JVM that store bytecode (and look machine friendly) so why View.class is same with normal class in java?

Comment: Looks like you're viewing a partially "decompiled" class file, not the original source file. My guess is that there's no attempt to decompile the code within the methods and so the exceptions are just a placeholder.

Comment: I don't really understand how Android's source code is organized, but I believe this is the `View.java` file you were trying to look at: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/View.java;drc=95709ba69f9285cceb4515d86eff55793bc96eec;l=14956

Comment: Thank you @Slaw, I got the answer right now

Comment: Oh, can I download this into my Android studio @slaw

Comment: tools > SDK Manager > Android SDK > SDK Platforms . On the bottom of the windows, check "show package details" then check find your Build Version (i.e. 30 ) and check "Source for Android 30" and Ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that file is not a sources file. The file with .class is a "decompiled". If you want to see source code, download it from Android studio setting > SDK Manager > Android SDK > SDK Platforms

Comment: The real library will be used when the application is deployed to the emulator, real phone, or tests. The version you see has no implementation to reduce the side. In C world that would correspond to headers only (no class function body).

Comment: @AlexanderKosenkov Do i understand correctly that those empty implementations that only throw an exception are needed to just Androi Studio can do autocomplete ? Or they have another purposes?